# How to echo the post value received in post

Tags: php, post

I'm using image uploader plugin which is posting data in multi dimension array like shown below

```
Array
(
    [file] => {"input":{"name":"KE6Cc2ea2b584.jpg",
"type":"image/jpeg",
"size":61224,
"width":800,
"height":643},
"output":{"width":320,"height":180,

  "image"
    :"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/just an example of base 64 encoded image"},
  "actions":{"crop":{"x":0,"y":96.5,"height":450,"width":800 },
  "size":{"width":320,"height":320}}}
)
```

Now i tried lot to echo these post values like shown below

```
echo $_POST['file']; worked but brought all the data
echo $_POST['file']['output']; didn't worked
echo $_POST['file']['output']['image']; didn't worked
```

How can i get the value of these post

Comment: This is json. Decode it first.

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['file'])`

Answer (score 0):

When trying to echo out any sort of values while debugging, it's a good idea to see *exactly* what you're getting via `var_dump`. For example, instead of your echo lines, I'd simply put:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST['file']);
```

Check your output there and it should show you exactly what keys you have to work with.

Also, depending on **how** your plugin is sending the data, you may not get any actual keys. According to your comment about `$_POST['file']` printing all the output, it seems as though it's still a string. Try putting the JSON into an object, like so:

```
$test = json_decode($_POST['file']);
```

Or, if you'd prefer an associative array as mentioned:

```
$test = json_decode($_POST['file'], true);
```

Then get the output of `$test`:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: Then do the second part of the post. If you ever do a `var_dump` and it says "string" instead of "array", you've got JSON that needs parsed.

Comment: Ok now i have std class how to echo desired value?

Comment: Now that you've got an object, you can use `$test->input->name` for example. Or, if you'd prefer an associative array, use `$test = json_decode($_POST['file'], true);` which will allow you to do `$test['input']['name']`